# Error de codec en Pandas, Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

Descargue **pandas** en un ambiente virtual creado en **anaconda** sin embargo no me esta funcionando el modulo, aun no se el motivo.

Este es el error que manda:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'UTF-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 21: invalid continuation byte.

Les muestro la imagen con el error completo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis preguntas son:

¿Porqué sucede esto? y ¿Cuál es la forma de solucionarlo?

Comment: No pongas imágenes de tu código o de los mensajes de error, copia el texto siempre. Será más fácil para todos encontrar la información. Edita tu pregunta por favor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El fallo es por la diferencia en la codificación de caracteres y lo puedes solucionar indicando explicitamente el codec. Estando en windows lo más probable es que sea latin-1, así que la solución seria:

```
data = pd.read_csv("planillas.csv", encoding="latin")
```

Comment: Estimado, conoces alguna forma de deducir la codificación? 
Dado que, por ejemplo en mi caso, puedo recibir csv tanto en ANSI/Latin-1 como en Unicode UTF-8  u otra codificación por la misma entrada. Existe alguna solución escalable que no implique hacer un try/except por cada codificación posible? Como abordan este problema otras soluciones?

Comment: No había pensado en eso, déjame que le de un par de vueltas y te digo pronto. Recuerda editar tu pregunta para retirar la imagen y poner texto para que los buscadores encuentren más fácilmente tu pregunta y la traza de error.